# Character encoding issue when using Python3/mysqlclient to retreive data encoded in latin1

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm running into a character encoding issue when retrieving data from an older database that is using `latin1` encoding.  The problem is occurring when I try to retrieve characters from the database that fall in the `\x80` to `\x9f` range, which is the range that is different between MySQL's `latin1` (aka `windows-1252` in Python) and the official `latin1` (ISO-8859-1).

This is the stack that I'm using:

- MySQL database server version 5.1 with `latin1` encoding at the column level and `latin1-swedish-ci` collation at the table level.
- Django version 2.2 using Python3 and mysqlclient version 1.4.4.

As an example, I'm trying to retrieve the word "Isn't" from the database where the apostrophe is encoded as `\x92`.

If I don't pass a charset to the mysqlclient connection through Django settings, I get the error "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 5: invalid start byte".

If I pass latin1 as the codec to the connection, there is no error but the word renders to the page as "Isn t", with blank space where the apostrophe should be.

When I open up a separate python shell session and try the connection from the python command line, the result is "Isn\x92t".

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conex = MySQLdb.connect(host=<host>,db=<db>, user=<user>, passwd=<passwd>, charset="latin1")
>>> cursor = conex.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("select <field> from <table> where id=<id>")
1L
>>> cursor.fetchall()
((u'Isn\x92t',),)
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference if I include the charset or not when making the call from the command line.  So this connection string

```
>>> conex = MySQLdb.connect(host=<host>,db=<db>, user=<user>, passwd=<passwd>, charset="latin1")
```

and this connection string

```
>>> conex = MySQLdb.connect(host=<host>,db=<db>, user=<user>, passwd=<passwd>)
```

have the same result.

Is there a way to set options for the mysql connection string that will handle the windows-1252 codes properly?  Any help would be appreciated.

=========  Edit with additional info  =========

Thanks for your response Rick James. The original text snippet went away, but I found another similar one that it's failing on:  Women's.

Here's the HEX select:

```
mysql> SELECT title, HEX(title) from <table> where id = <id>
| title | HEX(title)
| Women?s | 576F6D656E9273
```

I'm not sure I feel comfortable putting the entire create table statement online but here are what I figured were the important bits of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Let me know if you were looking for something else.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9460 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And lastly the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` results:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
```

Modifying the charset in the Django database settings file to `utf8mb4` resulted in the same unicode error as when it's set to `utf8`.

```
'OPTIONS': {
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'use_unicode': True,
}
```

I'm still a bit confused about why the direct query using a standalone python environment with `mysqlclient` wouldn't work.  That would at least take any of the Django issues out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

These charsets `cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8, latin1` treat x92 as `’` .

The setup for Django should specify the character encoding you want to use in the client.  This is independent of what is in the database.  So the question becomes "Where are things misconfigured."

The `u` introducer is wrong since 92 is not valid UTF-8.

- latin1 encoding at the column level -- fine
- 0x92 in the data -- Verify by doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`; `Isn't` should say `49736E9274`.
- Python source code should start with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` if you want to use UTF-8 in the client.
- Django needs this for utf8mb4 in the client:

  ```
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          ...
          'OPTIONS': {
                      'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                      'use_unicode': True, },
      },
  }
  ```

For more help, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
the SELECT HEX mentioned above
```

**Further notes** (after the Question was extended considerably)

`Woman?s` -- see question mark in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)  -- It is probably derived from having the connection (char%) being latin1, but the client (DJango) talking utf8mb4.  3 of the char% settings declare what the *client* is using for encoding; the DJango setting contradicts that.  Change one or the other.  The table column does not need to match them; data will be converted as needed.  That is, the 92 in a latin1 column is OK even with character_client/connection/results = utf8mb4.

For this Question, utf8 and utf8mb4 will act the same.

Comment: All of the connection-related charset settings in the DB are set to 'latin1', but when I tried setting the 'charset' option in the Django settings file to 'latin1', spaces are printed instead of an apostrophe.  This seems consistent with the wrong latin1 being used to decode the data from mysql (i.e. the real latin1 is being used instead of the MySQL version of latin1).  Is there some other setting I should be trying?  Or some other value for the charset option in Django settings?

Comment: The angled apostrophe in latin1 in MySQL is hex 92, so I do not buy that explanation.  I suspect Django and char... need to agree.  Try both at utf8mb4.

Comment: I can't modify the database at all.  Any adjustments for character sets need to be on the client side.

Comment: @Sanjuro - In the client, perform `SET NAMES utf8mb4` and meanwhile, have Django configured to utf8mb4.